# RecordLinkage - R one vector. Do not match to self

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-logic, stringdist, record-linkage

If I have one vector of names, say:

```
a = c("tom", "tommy", "alex", "tom", "alexis", "Alex", "jenny", "Al", "michell")
```

I want to get use `levenshteinSim` or similar to get a similarity score within this vector. However, I don't want it to self score. For example, `"tom" #1` to score against `"tom" #3`. And not to return a score for `"tom" #1` against `"tom" #1` so not to self score.

I have done it previously with two different vectors `a` and `b`. However, if I use this for the same vectors then  `"tom" #1` will score against  `"tom" #1` which is what I want to avoid.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What format do you expect for your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combn` to generate all unordered pairs of elements of `a`:

```
a <- c("tom", "tommy", "alex", "tom", "alexis", "Alex", "jenny", "Al", "michell")

df <- data.frame(t(combn(a, 2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$sim <- RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(df$X1, df$X2)

head(df)
#    X1     X2 sim
# 1 tom  tommy 0.6
# 2 tom   alex 0.0
# 3 tom    tom 1.0
# 4 tom alexis 0.0
# 5 tom   Alex 0.0
# 6 tom  jenny 0.0
```

Comment: With larger sets I receive an error - Is there a way using combn to set a key (based on another variable) so that only combinations with matching keys are returned?